# SQL Server : SELECT Column A from Column B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, matching, multi-table

First, I hope the topic title wasn't too vague, I'm not really sure how to describe this issue.

I have been handed an inventory database that was grown and developed by a few generations of people with varying levels of skill. Now it have tons of gotcha's of things that look alike but aren't quite.

So, while there is a table with cost adjustments for every type of inventory. It is unused instead someone took the time to pre-calculate every possible price and add it to each line of the inventory table:

```
SELECT Part#, CategoryID, StdCost, ListPrice, Level1, Level2, Level3 
FROM [Inventory] 
WHERE ...
```

Each row of the `[Customers]` table has a `PriceLevel` column that contains one of these values: `Level1, Level2, Level3`. But now I just found out there is yet another table, for a small subset of customers that get additional discounts. Finding `E.DiscountLevel` with a `Left Join` was easy the help I am looking for is with the last column, this other discount table also overrides the customer `PriceLevel` with a new one for specific categories. I am not sure if it can be done at all or not, but can a cell value from one table be used as a column name in another table of the same `SELECT`?

Table `[Inventory]` has columns `Level1, Level2, Level3`, table `[InventoryDiscounts]` has a column `PriceLevel` that contains the *Word* `Level1`. Should I just use a second query, or is it possible to somehow `SELECT B.(E.Column)`

This is the whole query with its many joins. No **Bold** inside comment blocks, but you can see the Stars around the trouble spot.

```
SELECT 
    A.InventoryID, B.Description, D.Category, 
    B.ListPrice, B.Level3 AS Price,
    E.DiscountLevel, **B.(E.PriceLevel) AS AltPrice**
FROM 
    [BranchInventory] A 
INNER JOIN 
    [Inventory] B ON A.InventoryID = B.InventoryID 
INNER JOIN 
    [Branches] C ON A.BranchID = C.BranchID  
INNER JOIN 
    [Categories] D ON B.CategoryID = D.CategoryID 
LEFT JOIN 
    [InventoryDiscounts] E ON E.CustomerID = 32 AND B.CategoryID = E.CategoryID
WHERE 
    A.BranchID = 8 
    AND A.InventoryID = 1181691
```

I expect the answer is going to be 'Just use an extra query', and that is ok. But frequently you guys are able to work some crazy magic, and I would love it if that was the case.

Comment: `coalesce()`???

Comment: I'd like to learn to improve future question quality. Can I please get some notes on why the down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql):

```
SELECT A.InventoryID
    ,B.Description
    ,D.Category
    ,B.ListPrice
    ,B.Level3 AS Price
    ,E.DiscountLevel
    ,CASE 
        WHEN E.PriceLevel = 'Level1'
            THEN B.Level1
        WHEN E.PriceLevel = 'Level2'
            THEN B.Level2
        WHEN E.PriceLevel = 'Level3'
            THEN B.Level3
        END AS AltPrice
FROM [BranchInventory] A
INNER JOIN [Inventory] B ON A.InventoryID = B.InventoryID
INNER JOIN [Branches] C ON A.BranchID = C.BranchID
INNER JOIN [Categories] D ON B.CategoryID = D.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN [InventoryDiscounts] E ON E.CustomerID = 32
    AND B.CategoryID = E.CategoryID
WHERE A.BranchID = 8
    AND A.InventoryID = 1181691
```

Comment: Ha! Brilliant, Thank you, this worked. I haven't done much with CASE more than once or twice before.  This'll save be a bunch of hassle to get all as one result.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best performance would be had if you spelled it out as a  case. Simply select the correct column B based based on E. Pricelevel

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql